# Magento - making a new getProductCollection() function

Tags: magento

Currently, if I want to get a certain collection of products, for example best-selling, I use the following, direct in my template file:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('name')
->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)
->addOrderedQty()
->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
$_productCollection->load();
```

...and then pull out the products with a foreach statement.

Can anyone explain how to make a new block to do this, that can be re-used? I've found a few examples but they always call the product list from a CMS page, whereas I want to have the call to the function embedded directly in a template file, that I can call from anywhere.

So presume I have my module set up, and my Bestseller.php file in my Block folder. In it I guess I put my function for the collection, something like

```
protected function _getBestsellingCollection()
{
$_BestsellingCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('name')
->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)
->addOrderedQty()
->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
$_BestsellingCollection->load();
}
public function getLoadedBestsellingCollection()
{
    return $this->_getBestsellingCollection();
}
```

And if so, how then do I call that from my template? Something like?

```
$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedBestsellingCollection()
```

Any help, or pointers to decent tutorials, much appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

I'm getting closer, but I'm having trouble with extending the **Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection** class. If I add my code to the end of the **Collection.php** file, like

```
public function addBestSelling()
{
$this->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addOrderedQty()->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc'); 
return $this;
}
```

and then use

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addBestSelling();
```

in my phtml template file, it works fine. But if I separate that code into my **Bestseller.php**, in my Models folder of my module, like so

```
class Samsmodule_FeaturedProducts_Model_Bestseller extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection
{
public function addBestSelling()
{
    $this->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addOrderedQty()->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
    return $this;
}
}
```

and then try and use it with the following, I get an error where the page doesn't finish loading (no error message)

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('featuredproducts/bestseller')
->addMostViewed();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: +1 for a well-worded question with lots of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocks are for rendering HTML.  Each Block Object has a phtml template object.  When you use `$this` from a phtml template you're referring back to the containing block object.

It doesn't sounds like you're rendering HTML.  It sounds like you want to fetch a specific list of products to **use** in any block/template.

If the above assumptions are correct, instead of creating a new Block you want to create a new Model Collection class that extends the class of the object returned by

```
Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection').
```

Add your method to that class, and call it with something like

```
Mage::getResourceModel('mymodule/my_collectionclass')-> getLoadedBestsellingCollection()
```

Comment: Thanks Alan. Read some of your posts on your site and it's getting clearer! So, say I have Bestseller.php in my modules Model folder - the class is **Samsmodule_FeaturedProducts_Model_Bestseller** - do I just add my same call for the **_getBestsellingCollection** as in my question? And then call it in my template using **$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('featuredproducts/bestseller')->getLoadedBestsellingCollection()**? I tried this and it's not working, so I think I'm still missing something! I do have my models set up correctly as I'm adding stuff to the admin with this module.

Comment: You're creating a new class.  There's nothing special about Samsmodule_FeaturedProducts_Model_Bestseller.  It's just the a default model.  You're going to define a **new** class which extends the reports/product_collection.  Then you can add methods to your hearts content.

Comment: Roll up your sleeves and do some good old fashioned debugging.  My guess is that getResourceModel isn't returning an object because your URL/Class has the wrong naming convention.  Take a look at _getResourceModelFactoryClassName to see what the system wants.  (also, Check the magento system log as well as the PHP error logs)

Comment: See the new thread for a more in-depth question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877263/magento-extending-the-mage-catalog-model-resource-eav-mysql4-product-collection